# iOS Autolayout same width constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've got a layout which I want to look like this:

```
Location:    "blabla"
Website:     "blabla"
LongerLabel: "blabla"
```

I want all the labels to be the same width. Hardcoded this can look like this:

```
@"H:|[locationLabel(80)]-5-[location]|"
@"H:|[websiteLabel(80)]-5-[website]|"
@"H:|[remarksLabel(80)]-5-[remarks]|"
```

I've already tried this using circular reference which doesn't work ;)

```
@"H:|[locationLabel(websiteLabel)]-5-[location]|"
@"H:|[websiteLabel(remarksLabel)]-5-[website]|"
@"H:|[remarksLabel(locationLabel)]-5-[remarks]|"
```

I do not want my labels to be hardcoded to 80, but I want them all the same width according to the max intrinsic content size.

Comment: Try like this `@"H:|[locationLabel(==websiteLabel)]-5-[location]|"`

Comment: Tried it, docs say they're optional in that case and it didn't work same result as without

Comment: ooops, missed a point. This won't work unless you specify the width of at-least one particular element in horizontal direction. Say `locationLabel` and `location` are spread over full screen horizontally. Now system doesn't know what each of them have the width of. `locationLabel` can be equal width to `websiteLabel` or `remarksLabel` but doesn't have a resolvable width in run time. So either decide that both `locationLabel` and `location` will also have the same width or any specifc ratio OR given any one of it a fixed width. That should solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using circular greater-than-or-equal-width constraints:

```
@"H:|[locationLabel(>=websiteLabel)]-5-[location]|"
@"H:|[websiteLabel(>=remarksLabel)]-5-[website]|"
@"H:|[remarksLabel(>=locationLabel)]-5-[remarks]|"
```

[image: Labels with applied constraints]

(sorry for weird colors :) )

**UPDATE**: I've just checked simple "equal" circular constraints, and they work in my case as well. However, I think, "equal" constraints don't specify the "main" label in any way, they just state, that labels should be equal. And if they are all equal to the smallest label, it is also fine. So in the "equal" case it probably depends on the order of constraints.

Now let's take a look at two hypothetical labels ("Label" and "Label label" (LL for shortness)), which are connected using ">=" constraints.

*Warning: the following text is just an assumption, I've never seen an actual autolayout implementation. I just know that it uses a complicated linear equations solving system to find a solution which satisfies all constraints as close as possible.*

The autolayout engine (AE) takes the first label and makes it as small as possible because of the content hugging. The LL is ignored for now. Then the AE takes the second label. In case of equal constraints it would have to make it short, like the first labels, because the first label has already been processed. But in case of ">=" constraint the AE can make the second label longer. However, now it affects the "L >= LL" constraint and AE has to switch back to L and process it one more time using the new data (in case of "==" constraint it would stop already, because no conflicts emerged). The only solution now is to make the first label longer, which AE does, because it doesn't introduce any conflicts.

So, this way in several iterations the AE ends up with all labels being the same width (the width of the longest label).

Comment: Mmm it works. I know a fair bit about VFL, but I dont know why this works and not my circular reference ;). I will give you the correct answer, but if you got a spare minute could you explain why your answer works? P.S. the colors are fine and makes your answer better ;)!

Comment: Nice answer!!! - I think it works if you omit last constraint, I didn't tried it but it seems that last constraints not required, right?

Comment: @Kampai, thanks) It is not required in my example, because the last label is the longest, but if they were ordered differently (let's say LLL, LL, L), than it wouldn't work without the last constraint. The circular dependency ensures that no matter what label is the longest, it would propogate its length to all other labels.

Comment: @FreeNickname Thank you!!. What you are describing actually happened in my case. The third label got truncated. Got my upvote and best answer mark!

Comment: @ScareCrow, Thanks) I'm glad I could help)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify fix-same width constraints using Visual Formatting language.

Constraints will be like below:

```
@"H:|[locationLabel]-5-[location]|"
@"H:|[websiteLabel]-5-[website]|"
@"H:|[remarksLabel]-5-[remarks]|"
```

Below additional constraints are required:

```
// Width constraints for Left side labels
NSLayoutConstraint *locationLabelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.6 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:locationLabelConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *websiteLabelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.6 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:locationLabelConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *remarksLabelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.6 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:remarksLabelConstraint];


// Width constraints for right side labels
NSLayoutConstraint *locationConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.3 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:locationConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *websiteConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.3 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:websiteConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *remarksLabelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:locationLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.3 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:remarksConstraint];
```

**Explanation:**

Above all constraints are width constraints equally related to its parent view width, these means labels will take all full width of its parent view. Here you can change multiplier to fix labels width.

> Multiplier = 1 => Full view width
>
> Multiplier = 0.5 => Half view width

Observe left side label width constraint where multiplier = `0.6` which means that it will take `0.6`% space of `self.view` width.

Same way right side label width multiplier = `0.3` which takes `0.3`% space of `self.view`. Change these values as your convenience.

**Note:** Also please check Xcode console sometimes there constraints gives warnings about constraint conflict. If there is any warning please resolve by changing constraints properties.

Comment: But this just means the value are hardcoded to 0.6 of the parent. Which is not what I want. Then i am better of with the hardcoded values. Check my question for a deeper explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am missing something, but simple 'equal width' constraints should have sufficed (no need for >=). They did for me.

The default compression resistance priority (750) is greater than the default content hugging priority (250). So it all works out in the end.
[image]

Comment: I agree, that it should work. And I was also wondering about priorities. However, the OP explicitly stated in the question, that this solution didn't work for him for some reason, and I believe, I've faced a similar issue in the past. Hence the ">=" trick. To be fair, I couldn't reproduce a situation, when "==" doesn't work. But I believe, that such situation might indeed exist.